# Vb.net capture "+" keypress and add the value already in a cell of a datagridview to the new value entered

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i used to have some code that worked "kinda" ok for a stocktaking application. Where the user can scan a product and then enter the value of how many they have counted. i added the ability to be able to press the "+" key on the numpad and it would add the value that was already in the cell to the value you now entered in. so for example you counted 2 and then later you find more of the same product you now press + 5 and the cell would then show 7.

i had to use this stocktaking application today, and noticed the + function didnt work. when i looked at my code later tonight, there is no code there to handle the + and add the values. and for the life of me i cant remember how i got this working.

this is the code thats remaing so far.

STCellValue is a public integer value that stores the value already in the cell.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellBeginEdit...
 If Not IsDBNull(DataGridView1.Rows(rowindex).Cells("COUNTED").Value) Then

If STAddKeyPressed = True Then STCellValue = 
  CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(rowindex).Cells("COUNTED").Value)

ElseIf STAddKeyPressed = True Then

 STCellValue = 0

End If
```

STAddKeyPressed is a boolean public value that is changed to true on the keydown event for the datagridview.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(....
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
'does things for escape key
ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Add And FILE_Advanced_StocktakeMode.Checked = True Then
   STAddKeyPressed = True
end if
```

i then have this code in the datagridview cellbeginedit subroutine.

```
If Not IsDBNull(DataGridView1.Rows(rowindex).Cells("COUNTED").Value) Then

  If STAddKeyPressed = True Then STCellValue = 
    CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(rowindex).Cells("COUNTED").Value)

  ElseIf STAddKeyPressed = True Then

        STCellValue = 0

  End If
End if
```

obviously this does nothing with the Value in the cell, nor does it add the two together, i played around with several things, but cant get it work.

i would have thought that in:

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged
```

there would have been the code to handle the addition of the two values. but its not there.

at the moment if I press the + key on the numpad then a number, the cell will only record the number it will ignore the + and wont even leave it in the cell. so you don't end up with "+5" in the cell just "5". not sure how that's occurring to be honest.

like I said I did have this working in the past, but no idea why the code is now missing :/ I remember that it didn't always 100% of the time work the way it was intended but i didn't mind it was rare the issue would arise. I know im probably not going about the right way in handeling the key.down and events so if you can recommend a better way then im all ears!

Comment: The code in the `CellBeginEdit` looks a little strange. The two inner `IF` statements look odd.  The first inner `If` statement is… `If STAddKeyPressed = True Then …` … then in the `ElseIf` portion,  the code checks for the same condition … ? … `ElseIf STAddKeyPressed = True Then… ` … In its current state, the code will NEVER enter the `ElseIF` portion of code. Is this intended?

Comment: Also, I assume you may not be aware of this… but the `DataGridView1_KeyDown` event will NOT fire when the “+” Key is pressed. So I am confident that in the Grids `KeyDown` event, that the `if` condition… `If e.KeyCode = Keys.Add …` … will ALWAYS be `false.` It sounds like you may need to cast the edited cell to a `TextBox`, then wire up the text boxes `KeyPress` event. THEN that event WILL fire when the “+” Key is pressed. I am just saying that you will need to move to the individual cell level if you want to capture the keys pressed while the cell is in “edit mode.”

Comment: @JohnG actually i do have the cast to textbox in place already, i didnt include it as there wasnt any code in there that i thought was useful. like i said some how my code has been deleted. and getting it working again is my goal.

Comment: @JohnG - i got this working :) I had to add in the subroutine for CellEndEdit, and add the two values together there.